# How to determine when -fsanitize=memory is in use?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, msan

I want to clear a false positive on `FD_ZERO` and `FD_SET` when the memory sanitizer is in use. Clearing it is somewhat easy:

```
#include <sanitizer/msan_interface.h>
...

__msan_unpoison(&readfds, sizeof(readfds));
__msan_unpoison(&writefds, sizeof(writefds));
```

However, I don't know how to detect when the memory sanitizer is in use. That is, detect when `-fsanitize=memory` was specified on the command line. The preprocessor does not seem to be helping:

```
$ clang -dM -E -fsanitize=memory - </dev/null | egrep -i 'memory|sanitize|msan'
$
```

How can I determine when `-fsanitize=memory` is in use?

Comment: as a workaround, there is `-DSANITIZED_MEMORY`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Konstantin Serebryany on the [Memory Sanitizer mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/memory-sanitizer/O0H1kTnIUik), there is no preprocessor macro. The [__has_feature(memory_sanitizer)](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/MemorySanitizer.html#has-feature-memory-sanitizer) should be used:

```
#if defined(__has_feature)
#  if __has_feature(memory_sanitizer)
#    define MEMORY_SANITIZER 1
#  endif
#endif
...

#ifdef MEMORY_SANITIZER
#  include <sanitizer/msan_interface.h>
#endif
...

#ifdef MEMORY_SANITIZER
__msan_unpoison(&readfds, sizeof(readfds));
__msan_unpoison(&writefds, sizeof(writefds));
#endif
...
```